# is it haram? to do what I’m doing?

Tags: non-mahram

as salaamu alaikum, I don’t want unwanted sins so please help me inshallah. sooo basically I received Islamic reminders from a brother online I only like the post that’s all. its Ramadan so we stop chatting before we use to chat but when Ramadan came around we stopped he said he would only send reminders so is what we doing haram are we getting sins? please tell me.